# tensorflow initialize variable error

Tags: python, tensorflow

As you all know there are various ways to initialize your variables in tensorflow. I tried some stuff in combination with a graph definition. See the code below.

```
def Graph1a():
    g1 = tf.Graph()
    with g1.as_default() as g:
        matrix1 = tf.constant([[3., 3.]])
        matrix2 = tf.constant([[2.],[2.]])
        product = tf.matmul( matrix1, matrix2, name = "product")

    sess = tf.Session( graph = g )
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    return product

def Graph1b():
    g1 = tf.Graph()
    with g1.as_default() as g:
        matrix1 = tf.constant([[3., 3.]])
        matrix2 = tf.constant([[2.],[2.]])
        product = tf.matmul( matrix1, matrix2, name = "product")

    sess = tf.Session( graph = g )
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    return product

def Graph1c():
    g1 = tf.Graph()
    with g1.as_default() as g:
        matrix1 = tf.constant([[3., 3.]])
        matrix2 = tf.constant([[2.],[2.]])
        product = tf.matmul( matrix1, matrix2, name = "product")

    with tf.Session( graph = g ) as sess:
        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
        return product
```

Why is it so that `Graph1a()` and `Graph1b()` won't return product, while `Graph1c()` does? I thought these statements were equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `global_variables_initializer` needs to be associated with the same graph as the session. In `Graph1c` this happens because the `global_variables_initializer` is inside the scope of the with statement of the session. To get `Graph1a` to work it needs to be rewritten like this

```
def Graph1a():
    g1 = tf.Graph()
    with g1.as_default() as g:
        matrix1 = tf.constant([[3., 3.]])
        matrix2 = tf.constant([[2.],[2.]])
        product = tf.matmul( matrix1, matrix2, name = "product")
        init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    sess = tf.Session( graph = g )
    sess.run(init_op)
    return product
```

Comment: Too bad, this is not the case. I understand that it looks confusing, but g is already being defined by the with.. as g:
I also ran the code with your suggestion of change, and the same situation happened.

Comment: but the way that you have the identiation g becomes out of scope when the session is initialized

Comment: Okay, as I said before, I have tried your suggestion but it did not change the output. And to check again, I printed the operations of both graph g1 and g in the function.. which are identical.

Do you perhaps have any other suggestions? Would you consider this a bug?